# How to get AWS lambda function execution status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have two AWS Lambda function in the same serverless project. I have a requirement that these two lambda functions do not execute at the same time. If one lambda funtion is under execution, the second lambda function should throw an error. How to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if your requirement open for a architectural change, but this sounds like a good scenario for AWS Step functions. With step functions, you can track the status of multiple lambda functions with parallel, sequential executions and also trigger nested functions and decisions based on output of a function.
https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Comment: Excellent suggestion there. Go with that.

Comment: As Pubudu mentioned, Step functions will be useful to maintain the distributed state of your solution. If possible, could you please explain a bit more on your requirement. For example, (1) do you want only one Lambda execution run at a time (because a Lambda function can be invoked to generate multiple executions at any given time)? (2) should second Lambda function execution fail only if the same input provided to the first Lambda function?, (3) is there a reason that you do not implement both functions as a single function (it may simply what want to achieve without step functions)?

Comment: Thanks @PubuduJayawardana. Is there any way to queue the lambda function executions using AWS step functions.

Comment: You may trigger step function using sdk, cli, API Gateway or configuring a CloudWatch Event